# istio webhook failing with error dial tcp <ip>:443: connect: no route to host

Tags: kubernetes, istio

During pod creation, I am getting following error: 
`Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s: dial tcp <ip>:443: connect: no route to host`

Using istio 1.4.6 installed using `istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo`
and kubernetes installed on on-prem vm using `kubeadm init`

Comment: Hi, This issue can be seen in several different cases: 1. Routing between the sidecars and the Istio control plane is not active. 2. The node running the injector (or the sidecar) has firewall rules enabled which are managed outside of K8s's cloud provider and the correct ports are not open. 3. The node running the injector (or the sidecar) is overloaded and unable to complete the work in the allotted time. (30s default).

Comment: Check if kube-proxy is working correctly. Do You have enough resources to run istio cluster? Try to deploy example `nginx` deployment and see if it gets injected successfully.

Comment: Hi @piotr I have entirely disabled the firewall in all the nodes even after that I'm facing the issue. And as per the resources, I have enough of them. Is there a way to debug kube-proxy?

Comment: Follow this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#is-the-kube-proxy-working) from official kubernetes docs.